# Go: Вызов функции с циклом и паузами из GUI

Tags: golang, gui

Имеется программа, GUI построен на [WALK](https://github.com/lxn/walk). По нажатии кнопки нужно вызвать функцию, связанную с типом окна, и в цикле выполнять действия, внутри цикла имеется пауза. 
Чтобы проиллюстрировать суть задачи я немного модифицировал пример программы с странички walk, так чтобы он отражал суть моей потребности:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

import (
    "github.com/lxn/walk"
    . "github.com/lxn/walk/declarative"
    "strings"
)

type MyMainWindow struct {
    *walk.MainWindow

    outTE *walk.TextEdit
    inTE *walk.TextEdit
}

type Structure struct {
    Index int
}

func main() {
    mw := new(MyMainWindow)

    if _, err := (MainWindow{
        AssignTo: &mw.MainWindow,
        Title:   "SCREAMO",
        MinSize: Size{600, 400},
        Layout:  VBox{},
        Children: []Widget{
            HSplitter{
                Children: []Widget{
                    TextEdit{AssignTo: &mw.inTE},
                    TextEdit{AssignTo: &mw.outTE, ReadOnly: true},
                },
            },
            PushButton{
                Text: "SCREAM",
                OnClicked: func() {
                    mw.mainProcess()
                },
            },
        },
    }.Run()); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func delaySecond(n time.Duration) {
    time.Sleep(n * time.Second)
}

func (mw *MyMainWindow) mainProcess() {
    tmp := make([]Structure, 200)
    for i, item := range tmp {
        item.Index = i
        delaySecond(15)
        mw.outTE.SetText(strconv.Itoa(i) +" " + strings.ToUpper(mw.inTE.Text()))
    }
}
```

Но, если я делаю так, то во время выполнения цикла GUI намертво зависает. Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение, изначально ваш код выполняется в основной горутине, вызов **time.Sleep** ставит на паузу текущую горутину и тем самым ставит на паузу всё приложение целиком. Это описано в документации на [**time.Sleep**](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep), вот цитата 
"*Sleep pauses the current goroutine for at least the duration d*".
Самый простой вариант это запускать ваш код в новой горутине, т.е. вместо

```
OnClicked: func() {
    mw.mainProcess()
},
```

сделать

```
OnClicked: func() {
    go mw.mainProcess()
},
```

Либо если не хочется создавать отдельную горутину то можно заменить функцию delaySecond на такую:

```
func delaySecond(n float64) {
    start := time.Now()
    for {
        if time.Now().Sub(start).Seconds() > n {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы пробовали это скомпилировать? Таким образом функция просто не видит обьектов с mw и не может с ними общаться.

Comment: Это код прекрасно компилируется и работает. Если у вас компилятор ругается то напишите на что

Comment: Простите, запустил старый бинарник. Работает